# liferay messageboard link to first/last message in thread

Tags: liferay

i need to add a link to the first/last post/message to each message. at the moment there is a "Top" link that jumps to begin of page. i want it to jump to first post and an additional link "bottom" that jumps to last post of thread.

Adding the links is not the problem but is there a easy way to get the last message of a thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it:

because i need also a link to first message i created a more general private method that is called by 2 public methods (getLastMessageOfThread and ...):

```
    private Long getMessageOfThread(long threadId, boolean last) {
    Long result = null;
    try {
        List<MBMessage> threadMessages = MBMessageLocalServiceUtil.getThreadMessages(threadId, 0, messageCreateDateComp);
        if (Validator.isNotNull(threadMessages)) {
            result = last ? threadMessages.get(threadMessages.size() - 1).getMessageId() : threadMessages.get(0).getMessageId();
        }
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Problem on getting thread messages for thread id " + threadId + ", cause:", e);
    }
    return result;
    }
```

Then i hooked view_thread_message.jsp:

```
...
                <ul class="edit-controls lfr-component">
                <%
                    String firstMessageId = String.valueOf(MyMessageboardLocalServiceUtil.getFirstMessageOfThread(thread.getThreadId()));
                    String lastMessageId = String.valueOf(MyMessageboardLocalServiceUtil.getLastMessageOfThread(thread.getThreadId())); 
                    String firstMessageAnchor ="#" + renderResponse.getNamespace() + "message_" + firstMessageId;
                    String lastMessageAnchor ="#" + renderResponse.getNamespace() + "message_" + lastMessageId;
                %>
                <liferay-portlet:renderURL varImpl="lastMessageUrl">
                    <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/message_boards/view_message" />
                    <portlet:param name="messageId" value="<%=  lastMessageId %>" />
                </liferay-portlet:renderURL>

                <liferay-portlet:renderURL varImpl="firstMessageUrl">
                    <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/message_boards/view_message" />
                    <portlet:param name="messageId" value="<%=  firstMessageId %>" />
                </liferay-portlet:renderURL>

                <li>

                    <liferay-ui:icon
                        image="top"
                        label="<%= true %>"
                        url="<%= firstMessageUrl.toString() + firstMessageAnchor %>"
                    />
                </li>

                <li>

                    <liferay-ui:icon
                        image="bottom"
                        label="<%= true %>"
                        url="<%= lastMessageUrl.toString() + lastMessageAnchor %>"
                    />
                </li>
...
```

probably it could be don easier but i'am an absolute liferay noob. and for the sake of completeness here the used comparator:

```
    private static class MBMessageDateComparator implements Comparator<MBMessage> {

    @Override
    public int compare(MBMessage arg0, MBMessage arg1) {
        Long time0 = arg0.getCreateDate().getTime();
        Long time1 = arg0.getCreateDate().getTime();
        return time0.compareTo(time1);
    }

}
```

Assuming that the first message has the smallest time stamp (seems to be a correct assumption).